# How to remove X-B3 prefix form Sleuth logs

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to remove X-Span-Export":"true","X-B3-SpanId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0","X-B3-TraceId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0"}

form my log .

I have added below configuration to application.yml but no help.

**Application.yml**

spring:
application:
name: app-name
profiles: dev
sleuth:
sampler:
probability : 1.0
log:
slf4j:
whitelisted-mdc-keys: principal
baggage-keys: principal

**JSON Log**

```
 {"@timestamp":"2020-12-02T13:58:35.343+03:00","@version":"1","message":"Request {}helloChasis from chasis-ms","logger_name":"az.iba.ms.chasis.controller.ChasisController","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"traceId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0","spanId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0","spanExportable":"true","X-Span-Export":"true","X-B3-SpanId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0","X-B3-TraceId":"40bcdc1c4fcdb9c0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your own `logging.pattern.level` where you will define your own logging pattern. If you have one then you'll override the default Sleuth one.

Comment: logging:
  pattern:
    level: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

Comment: I have added something like that , i think is it needs a pattern rather than level. But it didn't started